# Is it possible to decrypt CMS with outdated certificate?

Tags: .net, cryptography

Is it still possible with .net EnvelopedCMS class to decrypt a CMS when the certificate with the private key is outdated?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I am still reading the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: Tests showed that the decryption with an expired certificate is still possible.